# Can you make a kubernetes container deployment conditional on whether a configmap variable is set?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-container

If I have a k8s deployment file for a `service` with multiple containers like `api` and `worker1`, can I make it so that there is a configmap with a variable `worker1_enabled`, such that if my `service` is restarted, container `worker1` only runs if `worker1_enabled=true` in the configmap?

Comment: You have to implement this within your containers. But I would not recommend to run two application-containers in the same pod.

Comment: Not exactly, but you can configure your `worker1` container to run a no-op command like `sleep inf` instead of an actual application depending on a value stored in your ConfigMap. But like @Jonas says, you would normally use separate deployments for these two services (so that you can separately scale the API from the workers, etc).

Comment: This is quite easy to do in [Helm](https://helm.sh): you can have a deploy-time configuration setting (not a ConfigMap value), and surround one of the Deployments' YAML manifests in a `{{ if .Values.worker1.enabled }}...{{ end }}` conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No.

According to [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#workload-resources-for-managing-pods), Pods in a Kubernetes cluster are used in two main ways:

> - Pods that run a single container. The "one-container-per-Pod" model is the most common Kubernetes use case; in this case, you can think of a Pod as a wrapper around a single container; Kubernetes manages Pods rather than managing the containers directly.
> - Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together. A Pod can encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These co-located containers form a single cohesive unit of service—for example, one container serving data stored in a shared volume to the public, while a separate sidecar container refreshes or updates those files. The Pod wraps these containers, storage resources, and an ephemeral network identity together as a single unit.

Unless your  application requires it, it is better to separate the worker and api containers into their own `pod`. So you may have one `deployment` for worker and one for api.

As for deploying worker when `worker1_enabled=true`, that can be done with [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/). You have to create a `chart` such that when the value of `worker1_enabled=true` is set, worker is deployed.

Last note, a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in kubernetes is an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.